# Most Common Value within Sublists

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I apologize in advance if this is unclear, I will try to explain everything as best I can! I am working with a data set in Google Sheets such that Column A is a list of student IDs and Column B is a list of student behaviors. It looks something like this:

```
A(ID)    B(Behaviors)
12345    Talking
54321    Out of Seat
98765    Lying
12345    Talking
12345    Lying
98765    Lying
```

The list is data set is quite large because it contains recorded data from the entire school population over the course of the year, and as you can see the entire student population is pooled in one list. I am looking for a way to find each students (identified by their IDs) most commonly assigned behavior. For example, for the above data, student 12345 would have 'Talking' listed as their most common behavior and student 98765 would have 'Lying' listed as their most common behavior.

Ideally, I want to create a separate spreadsheet that looks something like this:

```
A(ID)    B(Most Common Behavior)
12345    Talking
98765    Lying
54321    Out of Seat
```

Such that column A is a list of all the student's IDs and column B lists their most common behavior.

I found that I could use this formula:

```
=INDEX(Behaviors,MODE(MATCH(Behaviors,Behaviors,0)))
```

To pull out the most common value from the column containing scholar behaviors, but this formula gives me the most common behavior among the entire student population, so I am interested in modifying it so that the formula first looks at the student ID and then looks at the most common behavior within that sublist.

Please let me know if you require any further information. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar using PivotTables?  You could just create a PivotTable with ID as a Row Label and Behavior as a column label and Value.  Then it would just be a matter of copying/pasting those values and using a MAX formula to get the greatest behavior count.

Comment: Nice Solution(+1), I think that the formula for listing the most often observed behavior would be something like: `=INDEX(E$3:G$3,,MATCH(MAX(E4:G4),E4:G4,0))` depending on where you placed or copied the values from the Pivot Table.

Comment: Thanks for the idea and formula!!